# python regex to match both United States and Japan

Tags: python, regex

In effort to scrape a website to determine which country an IP is from I'm using the following.

```
This pattern will match Japan<\a>
'[A-Z]\w+\<\/a\>\s\s'

This pattern will match United States</a>
'[A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z]\w+\<\/a\>\s\s'
```

I'm trying to figure out how to write and expression that would match both cases along with possible other countries. All countries do start with a capital letter but, not all countries are two words. This is where I'm stuck.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import re

## Open Connection ##
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
url = ('http://www.ip-lookup.net')
oururl = opener.open(url).read()

## IP Addresss finder ##
theIP = re.compile('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}')
ip = re.search(theIP, oururl)

## Country finder ##
roughCountry = re.compile('[A-Z]\w+\<\/a\>\s\s')
Country = re.search(roughCountry, oururl)

## Host address finder ##
roughHost = re.compile('')
Host = re.search(roughHost, oururl)

## Print out ##
print "Your IP is:", ip.group()
print "Your Host is:", Host.group()
print "Your Country is:", Country.group()
```

Comment: To match one or 2 words, make the sub-expression for the second word (and its leading space) optional (by using `?`).

Comment: you can user or '|' as well

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that you're going down the right path here, but without more details about what you're trying to do that's hard to say.  First of all, regex is usually a terrible idea for parsing html.  In any case, to answer your specific question, the following pattern accomplishes the same as both of your examples:

```
([A-Z]\w+)( [A-Z]\w+)?\<\/a\>\s\s
```

Then to support three words you could use:

```
([A-Z]\w+)( [A-Z]\w+){0,2}\<\/a\>\s\s
```

However, I suspect that you don't really want to include `</a>` tag as part of the match.  If not, you could use a lookahead, like this:

```
([A-Z]\w+)( [A-Z]\w+){0,2}(?=\<\/a\>\s\s)
```

Comment: @TroyWilson I'm not sure what you mean by your update.  What is your question?

Comment: My question is how to get a regular expression to match both United States and Japan. If I use what I currently have it just shows up as States</a> and cuts off the United.

Comment: @TroyWilson I've already answered that.  Is there something about my answer that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Need more details about your patterns of oururl.
May this help?

```
    >>> tmp="This pattern will             match United States</a>      T his pattern will match Japan</a>                 " 
    >>> re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*)\<\/a\>\s\s', tmp) 
    ['United States', 'Japan']
```